# unable to scp a file with a space in name

Tags: shell, scp

[image]

Actually the problem is that on the image bellow.

Comment: don't post a screenshot when text will do.  copy and paste the text from your terminal into your question.  use the `{}` icon in the editor to format it as code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use two layers of quotes:

```
scp user4@192.168.186.162:"'/home/user4/Desktop/dir2/MAP/MAP FILE AFTER.PNG'" ~/Desktop/
```

The trick is that both ends of the connection want to do quote processing.  First, your local shell sees the outer quotes and strips them, turning `'/home/user4/...AFTER.PNG'` into a single command line argument, which is passed to the remote SSH server.

The remote SSH runs a shell of its own, which will also do quote processing.  So you need to use a second layer of quotes to keep the filename together on the remote end.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
scp -r user4@192.168.186.162:/home/user4/Desktop/dir2/MAP/MAP\ FILE\ AFTER.PNG ~/Desktop
```

Comment: This gives the same result as the command line in the question.  (I just tested it on my own server.)

Answer (score 0):

1) it would better to paste text.

2) try

```
scp "user@....AFTER.PNG" ~/Deskop/
```

with quote arround first argument.